Как создать фильтрацию через select на vue 3 с composition api?
у меня есть родительский компонент app.vue, где идет запрос и ответ с бэка, получаю все объекты массива.
в родительском компоненте передаю компоненты СardList и FilterBlock.
в фильтр блоке у меня есть селект, где есть поля all, alive, dead, unknown. при клике на all должны вернуться все объекты массива, а поля alive, dead, unknown фильтруются по статусу. при этом если выбираем по статусу, то в компоненте Card(одна карточка, лежащая в CardList), если alive, то будет span, где будет отображаться зеленый кружок, для dead красный, для unknown желтый.
в общем на all все объекты с разными статусами и соответствующими им кружками, при выборе alive будут отображены, только объекты с этим статусом и зеленым кружком, для dead и unknown такая же фильтрация с соответствующими для них цветом кружка.
как мне это реализовать, используя vue3 c composition api?

фильтр на composition api
ссылка
